# A simple python script to 'search text files for whole words' - with GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently building a small program that allows searching for phrases in actors' dialog, using transcribed text files from video clips. I run into a few issues as described below...

1. Create user input:

   ```
   # Get the SEARCH WINDOW
   root = tk.Tk()
   root.withdraw()
   root.option_add('*background', '#111111')
   root.option_add('*Entry*background', '#999999')
   searchPhrase = sd.askstring(
       "PhraseFinder v0.1     |     filmwerk.nyc 2021 ", "Type keyword, or entire phrase, to search...", parent=root,)>
   ```

   This seems to work fine. User input stored in `searchPhrase`...
2. Take user input from above (`searchPhrase`) and search a directory containing 800 text files ('whole word' search only - 'ignore case').

   ```
   # Do THE SEARCH, based on user input
   import glob
   import os
   rootDir = '/Volumes/audio/TRANSCRIBE/OUT'
   os.chdir( rootDir )
   for files in glob.glob( "*.txt" ):
       with open(files) as f:
           contents = f.read()
       if (re.search(r'\b'+ re.escape(searchPhrase) + r'\b', contents, re.IGNORECASE)):
               print( f )
   ```

   This outputs:

   ```
   <_io.TextIOWrapper name='FW_A01_2020-12-01_1856_C0004.txt' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>
   <_io.TextIOWrapper name='FW_A01_2020-12-01_1900_C0007.txt' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>
   ```

The search result is correct, but the output format is not what I expected. So I need to rename stuff here. Unless there's a better way to get (print) the results? Currently, this gets output by `print( f )`.

The only thing I need from this output is to grab the actual file name:
`FW_A01_2020-12-01_1856_C0004.txt and FW_A01_2020-12-01_1900_C0007.txt`.
Then I need to rename & add the full path and finally store those search results files (clip list) in a continuous list, formatted like this:

```
> '/Volumes/RAID/Data/Media/TWO_CHAIRS/footage/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1806_C0001/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1806_C0001_000000.dng', '/Volumes/RAID/Data/Media/TWO_CHAIRS/footage/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1806_C0001/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1806_C0001_000000.dng',
```

3. Rename the 'search result' filenames (and add the full path), then store them in a variable. Since I don't know (yet) how to pipe in my actual search results into this function, I'll get the `rootDir` instead to perform the 'rename' as a test.

   ```
   for currentFile in listofFiles:
   listofFiles = listdir(rootDir)
   for currentFile in listofFiles:
       sourceFile = rootDir + "/" + currentFile
       mainNameEnd = currentFile.find('.')
       newFileName = currentFile[:mainNameEnd] + '_000000.dng'
       dirLoc = currentFile[:mainNameEnd]
       fullPathName = "'" + mediaDir + project.GetName() + "/" + "footage" + "/" + dirLoc + "/" + newFileName + "'" + "," + " "
       print("Converting path name: " + fullPathName)
   ```

This outputs:

```
Converting path name: '/Volumes/RAID/Data/Media/TWO_CHAIRS/footage/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1806_C0001/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1806_C0001_000000.dng',
Converting path name: '/Volumes/RAID/Data/Media/TWO_CHAIRS/footage/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1812_C0003/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1812_C0003_000000.dng',
Converting path name: '/Volumes/RAID/Data/Media/TWO_CHAIRS/footage/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1856_C0004/FW_A01_2020-12-01_1856_C0004_000000.dng',
```

Great, exactly the output format I need. However, this only works with files found in `rootDir`. What I really need is to grab the 'search result' clip list and rename those files the same way. Also, the clip list needs to be a continuous line as shown earlier.

Once that's working I'll use the reformated clip list in the function below. This will then import the clips into an external app.

```
# Import clips from Search Result
# We insert the search_result_clip_list, separated by comma. 
clips = resolve.GetMediaStorage().AddItemsToMediaPool(search_result_clip_list)  # <-- clip list goes here 
print(search_result_clip_list)
```

In a nutshell, I can't figure out how to take my search results, create a list, and finally use that list in the function above.

Would someone know how to implement this properly?

python 3.6.8 | MacOS 10.13.2 | Davinci Resolve 15

Comment: You have assigned the name of each file to the variable `files`.  `f` is the file object that you opened with that name.

Comment: you should use `print(files)` or eventually `print( f.name )` - but I would prefer first version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real file name is in variable `files` and you should simply use

```
print(files)
```

---

In `f` you have file-object which reads data from file - not file name -  and eventually you could use

```
print( f.name )
```

but I would prefer first version.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep all filenames which match regex then you should use list.

Before loop create `searchResult = []` and inside loop use `searchResult.append( files )`

```
searchResult = []

for files in glob.glob( "*.txt" ):
    # ... code ...
    if (re.search(r'\b'+ re.escape(searchPhrase) + r'\b', contents, re.IGNORECASE)):
        print( files )
        searchResult.append( files )
```

Comment: Yes. I used 'print( files)' as you suggested and that lists the filenames only! This is great. Is there a way to store the list in (Files) in a variable so I can use that later in the script? If so, how would I do that? I tried 'searchResult = files' and that (obviously:) didn't work.

Comment: standard rule: if you have many values then you have to use list. Before loop `searchResult = []` and inside loop `searchResult.append( files )`

Answer (score 0):

### To get all the names in the same list:

You can use an empty list and add items to it in each loop like this:

```py
my_names_list = []
for currentFile in listofFiles:
    sourceFile = rootDir + "/" + currentFile
    mainNameEnd = currentFile.find('.')
    newFileName = currentFile[:mainNameEnd] + '_000000.dng'
    dirLoc = currentFile[:mainNameEnd]
    fullPathName = "'" + mediaDir + project.GetName() + "/" + "footage" + "/" + dirLoc + "/" + newFileName + "'" + "," + " "
    print("Converting path name: " + fullPathName)
    my_names_list.append(fullPathName)
```

You will get a list with all the names as its items.
Respect of this: `However, this only works with files found in rootDir` I don't really get what you want, try to be more specific.

Comment: What I meant is that the rename function currently only works with a simple directory. I haven't figured out yet how to utilize the search results properly. I'll make some more explanations in the original post.